# How to display mandatory field and show error message in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

1. the application has a form that allows the user to select/multiselect
2. the content in the dropdown list are retrieved from a database, not hard coded:

   ```
   <select class="btn btn-default col-md-1" name="fy_dropdown" id="fy_dropdown">
       @foreach (var fy in Model.FYIndex)
       {
           <option value="@fy">@fy</option>
       }
   </select>
   ```
3. the layout (column name, style etc) of the form is in the script folder, as a .js file, the content in the dropdown list is in the view folder, as a .cshtml file.

so my question is 
1. why is the layout and content defined in separate places?
2. I want to make some fields marked with an asterisk, and if unselected, the field will display a warning (like a red box) at client side. How should I do it? Should I add some required attribute in the cshtml file?
3. I want the field to display to the user which one/several fields are selected. How should I do it?
4. Since under each field there are many options, how do I implement a search box (case insensitive) inside the dropdown list?

I am new to the mvc model, so I really appreciate any help that can help me understand, thanks!

Comment: Strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and learn the basics.

Comment: To answer your second question: it seems you are using a model called FYIndex. Add [Required] to each fields that are required in you FYIndex model.

Comment: Add 4): you can use [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: MVC already comes with built-in validation.

To make a property required, annotate it with a `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]` attribute in the ViewModel.
You can also provide a custom error message by referencing a key in a resx file. This key should have a placeholder for the name of the property.

Example:

```
DataAnnotationsResources.resx
<data name="RequiredAttribute_ValidationError" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The {0} field is required.</value>
</data>

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class ExampleCreateViewModel {
    // Name is required for create!
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(DataAnnotationsResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError")]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

To render required fields with an asterix, you can use the following extension method for the HTML helper. It uses the built in Html.LabelFor helper and YAML `ym-required` class to style the asterix.

```
/// <summary>
/// Renders a Label for the Property
/// If [DisplayName] Attribute was set, it uses it as Translation Key
/// Else it uses the Property Name as label
/// If Required Attribute was set and <see cref="showHint"/> == <code>true</code>, attaches an red asterix * to the label
/// </summary>
/// <param name="html">HTML Helper object.</param>
/// <param name="metaDataAccessor">Lambda to access the property that contains the metadata (DisplayName, Required Attributes)</param>
/// <param name="forFieldAccessor">Lambda to set the property that is referenced by the "for" HTML attribute of the &lt;label&gt; tag</param>
/// <param name="showHint">Set to <code>false</code> to never show the red asterix * even if the Property is required (e.g. not nullable value Properties like <code>bool</code>)</param>
public static MvcHtmlString LabelForPlusHint<TModel, TMetaDataValue, TForFieldValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TMetaDataValue>> metaDataAccessor,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TForFieldValue>> forFieldAccessor,
    bool showHint = true) {

    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(metaDataAccessor, html.ViewData);

    var label = html.LabelFor(forFieldAccessor).ToHtmlString();

    if (metadata.IsRequired && showHint) {
        label = label.Replace("</label>", "<sup class=\"ym-required\">*</sup></label>");
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(label);
}

public static MvcHtmlString LabelForPlusHint<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> metaDataAccessor, bool showHint = true) {
    return LabelForPlusHint(html, metaDataAccessor, metaDataAccessor, showHint);
}
```

Usage example: `@Html.LabelForPlusHint(m => m.Name)` to render Label for the required 'Name' porperty.